# Does Flyway support defining the list of sql migrations on a file?

Tags: flyway

In Flyway I was not able to use a file defining the exact ordered set of migration scripts (similar to [Liquibase approach](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog.html)).

Is there any way to do so, other than implementing my own `MigrationResolver`?

Answer (score 2):

Flyway does not require you to list your migrations in another file. Instead Flyway migrations are ordered by the version number for [versioned migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/versioned) and applied in that order. Versioned migrations start with a V by default. Your migrations need to have version numbers according to the sequence they should be applied. This avoids the need to duplicate the sequence in a file by making it explicit in the version number. I recommend leading zeros in your numbers to make them sort nicely on the filesystem too.

For example:

```
V100__new_feature_a_part_1.sql
V110__new_feature_a_part_2.sql
V111__new_feature_a_part_3.sql
V120__new_feature_b.sql
```

Comment: Sure, but sometimes I'd prefer a declarative approach, where the full ordered set of migrations is defined within a file.

Comment: @DavideCavestro, you could give Flyway a directory per "set" of migrations then enable ignoreMissingMigrations. A disadvantage of this approach is that you won't be able to recreate the database from scratch.

Comment: @DavideCavestro I agree this is a severe weakness of the product as a migration manifest would allow merging safely and explicitly in version control.